# gif animation that changes frame on download

Tags: javascript, html, download

Is there a way, using HTML, JavaScript and/or CSS, to change each GIF animation frame on download?

For example, if download = 10kb, gif animation frame = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript cannot control GIF animation at all. There are [some libraries](https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js) which do something similar, but in fact they parse the GIF file and render its subimages on a `<canvas>`. You would be better off using [sprites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Image_Sprites) to display a changeable image on your page.

Not sure what you mean by "on download", though. JavaScript cannot interface with downloads - it is between the browser and the server at that point, with no relation to the page that started the download. But you could do a fancy sockety thing that would communicate with the server and ask it how the download is going, then updating the page.

Comment: OK. thanks for answering. is there any other language I could use that would accomplish what I'm after?

Comment: Not if you are showing stuff to a user in a browser, no. Or rather, if my second paragraph is correct, you will have to also use serverside scripting, which would be best if you could use socket.io (or similar) package, which are best in JavaScript. This is not trivial though.